# Plug a PDB in a new CDB without XML manifest

Tags: oracle-12c, multi-tenant

In oracle 12c the **ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE "PDB1" UNPLUG INTO 'PDB1.XML'** statement create the XML manifest.
Is it possible to plug a PDB in a new CDB if it isn't correctly unplugged first and the source CDB isn't active?

Comment: Seems that there is no simple way to achieve this. PDBs doesn't have control files and redo logs, and if not unplugged there isn't no XML manifest. So, AFAIK, you can't do a recover without control files and redologs, and this means that first have to recover the entire CDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can recover the XML file of a not unplugged PDB.

1. COPY the PDB folder into the CDB folder on the new machine.
2. Connect as SYSDBA to the new CDB (I use SQLDeveloper)
3. EXECUTE the package **DBMS_PDB.RECOVER**

it uses 3 parameters:

1. /path/to/new/file.xml
2. NAME_OF_PDB (you can use the same as OLD PDB or a NEW ONE)
3. /path/to/pdb/folder/

EXAMPLE:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_PDB.RECOVER (
  pdb_descr_file => '/path/to/new/file.xml.xml',
  pdb_name => 'NAME_OF_PDB',
  filenames => '/path/to/pdb/folder/'
  );
END;
/
```

THEN, you can plug the database using:

```
CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE NAME_OF_PDB USING '/path/to/new/file.xml' NOCOPY TEMPFILE REUSE;
```

THEN open the PDB:

```
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE NAME_OF_PDB OPEN FORCE;
```

IF PDB DON'T OPEN, check PDB_VIOLATIONS

```
SELECT * FROM PDB_PLUG_IN_VIOLATIONS;
```

SOURCE
http://www.oraclebuffer.com/oracle/oracle-12c-lost-your-pdbs-xml-manifest-file-heres-how-you-can-recover-it/

Comment: I can't try this procedure by now but I found reference also on [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_pdb.htm#ARPLS74910). You can add the link to your answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the PDB in the source CDB, you do not need to unplug the PDB, you can just simply clone the PDB to another CDB:

- Have a user in the source PDB or CDB with the `CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE` privilege
- Open the source PDB in read-only mode
- In the target CDB, create a database link to the source PDB with the above user
- In the target CDB: `CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE pdbclone FROM pdbsource@dblink;`

More details at:

[Cloning a Remote PDB or Non-CDB](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_plug.htm#ADMIN13593)

Comment: Sorry, i was not clear, is there a way to do this without the source CDB active?